I am using RPC node service and cannot catch up with the latest block height
I need to configure my server with

2x AMD EPYC 7443
OS image Ubuntu 22.04 64bit,
RAM512GB 3200MHz,
OS diskNVMe 2TB，

I am using RPC node service and cannot catch up with the latest block height. This is my startup configuration for agave validator
\--identity /home/solv/identity.json 
\--log /home/solv/solana-validator.log 
\--accounts /mnt/accounts 
\--ledger /mnt/ledger 
\--entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
\--entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
\--entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
\--entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
\--entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
\--known-validator Certusm1sa411sMpV9FPqU5dXAYhmmhygvxJ23S6hJ24 
\--known-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 
\--known-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ 
\--known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S 
\--expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d
\--expected-shred-version 50093 
\--only-known-rpc 
\--enable-rpc-transaction-history 
\--full-rpc-api 
\--no-voting 
\--no-snapshot-fetch 
\--private-rpc 
\--dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 
\--rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0 
\--rpc-port 8899 
\--no-port-check 
\--rpc-pubsub-enable-block-subscription 
\--rpc-pubsub-enable-vote-subscription 
\--no-wait-for-vote-to-start-leader 
\--wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record 
\--use-snapshot-archives-at-startup when-newest 
\--limit-ledger-size 50000000 
\--accounts-db-skip-shrink 
\--accounts-index-memory-limit-mb 4096 
\--unified-scheduler-handler-threads 40 
\--rpc-threads 4 
\--snapshot-interval-slots 1000 
\--maximum-full-snapshots-to-retain 2 
\--maximum-incremental-snapshots-to-retain 2 \


Is there a reason you're using --no-snapshot-fetch? If you're just starting a new node, you'll need a snapshot from somewhere. Try removing that flag
